# Exact diagonalization of a random-field Heisenberg Model

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information

I am working with the random-field Heisenberg model:
$$
H = \sum_{j=1}^L\left[J\, \vec{S_j}\cdot \vec{S_{j+1}} - h_jS_j^z\right].
$$

I am interested in the phenomenon of many-body localization, and so I need to exactly diagonalize this Hamiltonian and get some high-energy eigenstates. Since the dimension of the Hamiltonian scales exponentially in system size $L$, I learned that we can use the fact that the $\sum_i S_i^z$ is conserved, and effectively reduce the dimension of the Hamiltonian to say $S_z^{total} = 0$ block, as explained in this article https://doi.org/10.21468/SciPostPhys.5.5.045.

However, I am confused, since diagonalizing only a block with $S_z^{total} = 0$ doesn't give the full information about the actual Hamiltonian's eigenstates, how does this method help? Say I want to study the entanglement properties of the eigenstates, how can I do that by just studying just this block, as they seem to have done in the above article?

Comment: You have to look at *all* Sz sectors, unless you have extra insight that Sz=0 has the relevant eigenstates. But the Sz=0 sector is the largest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I am confused, since diagonalizing only a block with $S_z^{total} = 0$ doesn't give the full information about the actual Hamiltonian's eigenstates, how does this method help?

It helps in the same way that, for example, $S_z$ being conserved in an atom helps. The fact that $S_z$ is conserved means that:
$$
[H, S_z] = 0
$$

For states $|M\rangle$ of a given $S_z$ value $M$, the matrix elements of the Hamiltonian between states of different $M$ have to be exactly zero. This follows from the above commutation relation since:
$$
\langle M|[H, S_z]|M'\rangle = \langle M|H|M'\rangle(M-M') = 0\;.
$$

So that, when $M\neq M'$ we have:
$$
\to \langle M|H|M'\rangle = 0\;.
$$

This means the Hamiltonian is "block diagonal." (It is a direct sum of smaller "blocks"/matrices, one for each $M$ value.)

---

So, this helps because you can concentrate on each fixed $S_z$ block one at a time instead of trying to diagonalize the total Hamiltonian all at once.

This can greatly reduce the time you need to exactly diagonalize a $N\times N$ matrix, which scales as $N^3$ ([in many cases](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455436/what-is-the-computational-complexity-for-diagonalizing-covariance-matrix)). For example, instead of having to diagonalize a $4 \times 4$ matrix, in time 64 units, you could reduce the problem to diagonalizing a $3 \times 3$ matrix and a $1 \times 1$ matrix, in time 28 units.

In the above example, we have supposed that the 4x4 Hamiltonian can be reduced to a block diagonal form in terms of a direct *sum* of a 3x3 matrix and a 1x1 matrix, which commonly occurs in the physics of two-electron atoms. You use the fact that $S_z$ commutes with the Hamiltonian to block diagonalize.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I understand that the Hamiltonian will be block diagonal. However, I was wondering whether, it's okay to pad the eigenvectors of the $S_z = 0$ block with zeros to make it the same dimension as H and then, say, study the entanglement properties? Will it make a difference if we had diagonalized the full Hamiltonian instead and then studied the entanglement?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's OK or not. What do you mean by "study the entanglement"? Does that involve an additional part to the Hamiltonian that doesn't conserve $S_z$? If not then it seems fine to "pad" the eigenvectors with zero outside the block for their given fixed $S_z$ value, since they would be zero there anyways.

Comment: Yes understood! Thanks!